# AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class error on creating the instance of my kotlin data class

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-cloud-config

I am getting the error on my container start :

> org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
> generate CGLIB subclass of class com.config.FeatureFlags: Common
> causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible
> class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
> subclass final class com.config.FeatureFlags

My Classes are as below

```
data class FeatureFlags(val name: String, val password: String)
```

And my Bean

```
@Configuration


class MyAppConfig {
@Value("\${myapp.username}")
var username: String

@Value("\${myapp.password}")
var password: String

@RefreshScope
@Bean
fun myBean(): FeatureFlags{
    return FeatureFlags(username, password)
} 
}
```

What is the error that I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RefreshScope` needs to be able to create a subclass of your `FeatureFlags` class. But your class is `data class` - so it is effectively final and thus cannot be extended.

From [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html): `Data classes cannot be abstract, open, sealed, or inner.`

You need to define `open class FeatureFlags`.